# What is vectorization?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

What does it mean to vectorize for-loops in Python? Is there another way to write nested for-loops?

I am new to Python and on my research, I always come across the NumPy library.

Answer (score 38):

Python `for` loops are inherently slower than their C counterpart.

This is why `numpy` offers vectorized actions on `numpy` arrays. It pushes the `for` loop you would usually do in Python down to the C level, which is much faster. `numpy` offers vectorized ("C level `for` loop") alternatives to things that otherwise would need to be done in an element-wise manner ("Python level `for` loop).

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import Timer

li = list(range(500000))
nump_arr = np.array(li)

def python_for():
    return [num + 1 for num in li]

def numpy_add():
    return nump_arr + 1

print(min(Timer(python_for).repeat(10, 10)))
print(min(Timer(numpy_add).repeat(10, 10)))

#  0.725692612368003
#  0.010465986942008954
```

The `numpy` vectorized addition was x70 times faster.

Comment: For anyone that is wondering **why** vectorized operations are so much faster (on a hardware level) can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091979/why-is-vectorization-faster-in-general-than-loops).

Comment: Stating that numpy pushes for loops to C (and not explaining how vectorization is done there (and a level lower where machine byte code executes)) is not enough.

Answer (score 21):

Here's a [definition](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-for-data/9781449323592/ch04.html) from Wes McKinney:

> Arrays are important because they enable you to express batch
>   operations on data without writing any for loops. This is usually
>   called vectorization. Any arithmetic operations between equal-size
>   arrays applies the operation elementwise.

Vectorized version:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.]])
>>> arr * arr
array([[  1.,   4.,   9.],
       [ 16.,  25.,  36.]])
```

The same thing with loops on a native Python (nested) list:

```
>>> arr = arr.tolist()
>>> res = [[0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0.]]
>>> for idx1, row in enumerate(arr):
        for idx2, val2 in enumerate(row):
            res[idx1][idx2] = val2 * val2
>>> res
[[1.0, 4.0, 9.0], [16.0, 25.0, 36.0]]
```

How do these two operations compare?  The NumPy version takes 436 ns; the Python version takes 3.52 µs (3520 ns).  This large difference in "small" times is called microperformance, and it becomes important when you're working with larger data or repeating operations thousands or millions of times.