# How to use openBLAS to improve vectorized operations?

Tags: c, numpy, optimization, vectorization, openblas

I am self-learning how to write efficient, optimized deep learning code; but I am very much a newbie at this.

For example: I am reading that `numpy` uses [vectorization](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-faster-numpy-vectorized-code-or-hand-written-C-code) to avoid [python loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47755634/1158977).

They have also pretty much coined the term [broadcasting](https://machinelearningmastery.com/broadcasting-with-numpy-arrays/) according to that link, which is used by TensorFlow, PyTorch and others.

I did some digging, and found that `ldd` on my Debian box shows `multiarray.so` links `libopenblasp-r0-39a31c03.2.18.so`.

So let's take the use case of a matrix subtraction.  I would like to understand how to use openBLAS to improve this very naive implementation:

```
void matrix_sub(Matrix *a, Matrix *b, Matrix *res)
{
  assert(a->cols == b->cols);
  assert(a->rows == b->rows);

  zero_out_data(res, a->rows, a->cols);

  for (int i = 0; i < (a->rows*a->cols); i++)
    {
      res->data[i] = a->data[i] - b->data[i];
    }
}
```

Like wise an inner product, or an addition?