# Why numpy's where operation is faster than apply function?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

While creating a new column in pandas dataframe based on some condition, numpy's where method outperforms the apply method in terms of execution time, why is that so?

For example:

```
df["log2FC"] = df.apply(lambda x: np.log2(x["C2Mean"]/x["C1Mean"]) if x["C1Mean"]> 0 else np.log2(x["C2Mean"]), axis=1)

df["log2FC"] = np.where(df["C1Mean"]==0,
                        np.log2(df["C2Mean"]), 
                        np.log2(df["C2Mean"]/df["C1Mean"]))
```

Comment: `apply` is syntactic sugar for looping row-wise. In your other snippet it's acting on the entire columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This call to `apply` is row-wise iteration:

```
df["log2FC"] = df.apply(lambda x: np.log2(x["C2Mean"]/x["C1Mean"]) if x["C1Mean"]> 0 else np.log2(x["C2Mean"]), axis=1)
```

`apply` is just syntactic sugar for looping, you passed `axis=1` so it's row-wise.

Your other snippet

```
df["log2FC"] = np.where(df["C1Mean"]==0,
                        np.log2(df["C2Mean"]), 
                        np.log2(df["C2Mean"]/df["C1Mean"]))
```

is acting on the entire columns, so it's vectorised.

The other thing is that `pandas` is performing more checking, index-alignment, etc.. than `numpy`.

Your calls to `np.log2` are meaningless in this context as you pass scalar values:

```
 np.log2(x["C2Mean"]/x["C1Mean"])
```

performance-wise it would be the same as calling `math.log2`

Explaining why numpy is significantly faster or what is vectorisation is beyond the scope of this question. You can see this: [What is vectorization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47755442/what-is-vectorization).

The essential thing here is that numpy can and will use external libraries written in C or Fortran which are inherently faster than python.

Comment: Thanks, EdChum, Can you also explain how numpy makes the vectorized operations faster. Is it because of parallelization using threading or multiprocessing?

Comment: if we use broadcast as result type will this help to vectorize the apply? it doesn't have sense, apply should be smart enough.

Comment: @prosti that won't make any difference, that param is for determining what shape will be returned, here as it's row-wise it's irrelevant

Comment: @ashish14 see update, it's beyond the scope of this answer