# vectorize a function that changes values of a column conditionally

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have been wondering how to vectorize the function below for my dataframe. And can anything be vectorized?

Here is my dataframe:

```
                    date    AGE
   0    28/04/2017 13:08    25
   1    28/04/2017 08:58    87
   2    03/05/2017 07:59    23
   3    03/05/2017 08:05    45
   4    04/05/2017 08:05    26
   5    05/05/2017 08:05    10
   6    06/05/2017 08:05    56
   7    07/05/2017 08:05    39
```

Here is the function I want to use for vectorisation:

```
def decision(value):
    if  value>40:
       return 1
    return 0
```

I do not want to use np.where, or any lambda expression.

Comment: Why would you ask for a vectorized approach and then say that you don't want to use `np.where()`? That doesn't make sense

Comment: you dont want to use `np.where()` directly on the df column?, or you dont want to use `np.where()` even inside the function eg: `def decision(value): return np.where(value>40,1,0)`?

Comment: @roganjosh just because I heard its more efficient and I never really vectorized anything. so this is my beginning.

Comment: That comment totally baffles me. You want to vectorize something and you're rejecting a vectorized approach.

Comment: I want to use **np.vectorize** @roganjosh

Comment: @Camue perhaps read how [vectorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47755442/what-is-vectorization/47755634) works , try and operate directly on columns rather than rows id that is possible. With this usecase it is possible to operate on columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`Series.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html)  + [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html).

This is much faster and more efficient than `apply` method. Query: [`when should I use apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code)

```
df['Age'].gt(40).astype(int)


#def decision(age):
#    if age>40:
#        return 1
#    return 0
#    
#df['AGE'].apply(decision)
```

Comment: For correctness I deleted my answer, however I think you should expand explaining the solution and not just type "use: This...", which would not give much of an idea to the OP

Comment: This code is self-explanatory, it might be interesting to know when to use apply( check edit) 
I consider it a mistake to use the method apply here. On the other hand I don't think there are reasons to downvote

Comment: I actually was the first to upvote your answer sir. I am just saying that from the question I deduce that who posted it barely knows any pandas functionality or how vectorization works in in pandas.

Comment: @ansev. Thanks but I have used apply before and I am trying to get away from **applying**. is there a way to use np.vectorize create a new column.

Comment: Is the function you plan to apply the one you have shown or is it more complex? I do not understand why not use the solution I proposed. Could you explain your problem more explicitly?

Comment: @ansev thanks for your prompt response. You got the problem perfectly. It's just that I want to use **np.vectorize**  for fun as I never used and apparently its good.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/) for a similar performance.

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True, nogil=True)
def decision(arr_in: np.array, decision_num: int) -> np.array:
    n = arr_in.shape[0]
    decision_arr = np.empty(n, dtype=numba.int64)
    for i in range(n):
        if arr_in[i] > decision_num:
           decision_arr[i] = 1
        else:
            decision_arr[i] = 0
    return decision_arr
```

and then create the column:

```
df['decision'] = decision(df['AGE'].to_numpy(), 40)
```

use [`.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) if pandas is older then 0.24