# Partial column sum of a matrix or nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, list-comprehension

The code listed below is an attempt to obtain a matrix with a partial column-sum of another, such that the rows, `row[r]`, of the resultant matrix is the partial column-sum of the original matrix from `row=0` to `row=r`.

For example, 
given

```
A = [[0,0,0],
     [4,5,6],
     [7,8,9],
     [10,11,12]]
```

I would like to obtain

```
B=[[0,0,0],
   [4,5,6],
   [11,13,15],
   [21,24,27]]
```

1. Is there an alternative that allow me to eliminate the for-loop in the following code and which allows me to use pure list-comprehension instead?
2. Do you consider list-comprehension will be more computational efficient than for-loops or map/lambda provided that the actual matrices I'm working on are relatively large?

My current code is below:

```
import numpy as np
# Define matrices M and S
M= np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])
H = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
# Define matrix S with: S[0] = [0,0,0,0] and S[r>0][c] = M[r][c]xH[r]
S = np.array([[x if r != 0 else 0 for x in [M[r][c] * H[r] for c in range(0, len(M[r]))]] for r in range(len(M))])
# initialize matrix L
L = np.array(np.zeros((int(len(M)),int(len(M[0])))))
#Update Matrix L: L[r][c] = Sum[S[0][c] to S[i=r-1][c]]
for r in range(0, len(L)):
        L[r] = [sum([row[i] for row in S[0:r+1]]) for i in range(0,len(S[0]))]
print("S", S)
print("L", L)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using numpy, the fastest way to do something is usually to use broadcasting, or vectorization. You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47755442/12366110), but basically this means to apply a function to an array of data all at once, rather than by iterating over the array by using a for-loop.

This may have been what you were alluding to when you talked about list-comprehensions, but these at heart are just a different way of writing for-loops.

The function you are looking for in this case is [`np.cumsum()`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html), using `axis=0` to indicate that we want to cumulatively sum over each column. This is a vectorized method of applying the logic you seek, and will be a lot faster than your for-loop solution on large matrices.

```
>>> A = np.array([[0,0,0],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
>>> np.cumsum(A, axis=0)
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [11, 13, 15],
       [21, 24, 27]], dtype=int32)
```

Below is a graph showing a comparison of the speed of this approach and the approach in your question, as matrix size increases, which shows that the vectorized approach tends towards being approximately 10,000 times faster.

[image]

**Code to generate:**

```
import perfplot
import numpy as np

def cdjb_cumsum(A):
    return np.cumsum(A, axis=0)

def ajbg_forloop(A):
    L = np.array(np.zeros((int(len(A)),int(len(A[0])))))
    for r in range(0, len(L)):
        L[r] = [sum([row[i] for row in A[0:r+1]]) for i in range(0,len(A[0]))]
    return L

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.rand(n, n),
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(20)],
    kernels=[
        cdjb_cumsum, ajbg_forloop
        ],
    xlabel='Size of Array (n*n)',
    )
```

Comment: I was definitely looking for some form of "cumsum". However, cumsum(axis=0) adds the last row inclusively; i.e., the ith-row of the resultant matrix is:  Bt[i] = A[0] + ...Al[i]. In case I needed B[i] = A[0] + ... A[i-1], I'd use: B = np.cumsum(A) - A. Is there a more efficient/compact way of constraining cumsum to exclude the last row?

Comment: @ajbg the snippet in your comment I would have thought would be the fastest way of applying that logic.