# Finding coefficients for approximations

Tags: python, variables, approximation

*I just would like to approximate any number, out of mathematical curiosity, purely in terms of e.*

Example: If I give n=7.3890, the program must return a=1,b=0, which is the best approximation(minimal error) for all whole number pairs(a,b)

```
from math import *
n=float(input("Enter a number to be approximated:"))
for a in range(10):
    for b in range(10):
            if ((e**2)*a)+(e*b)==n:
                print(a,b)
```

This program couldn't do so since it searches for exact values rather than approximate ones

Comment: Your approach is a little bit naive. [have you ever head of the discriminant](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/quadratic-equation.html)?

Comment: So you want to find all **real** numbers a, b, c in [0,10) for which ax^2+bx+c=n for given x,n? There could be rather a lot of them! Or what exactly do you want it to do?

Comment: Well I wanted to generalize it for higher powers of x as well. We dont have discriminants for them, do we?

Comment: Do you want to find _all_ solutions (which is impossible) or _any_ solution? In the latter case, pick any a and b, and c=x-ax^2-bx. Unless there are other constraints, which you _must_ mention in the question.

Comment: Do you want to create your own program or would a scipy implentation also work?

Comment: I would like to get some idea. I could go on creating my own code after that.

Comment: We may have infinite such ordered numbers(a,b,c). However good approximations mean (a,b,c) to be in simple fractions or just whole numbers

Comment: Without any additional constraint, the simplest solution is to set `a` and `b` to zero and `c` to `n`, which always hold regardless of the value of `x`.

Comment: @DatBoi So you would like to find "simple fractions" - also known as rational numbers. You should add that to the question. But without other constraints, there are still going to be too many solutions though (if x and n are rational then choose any rational a and b, and c is also rational).

Comment: Ah, now you've changed the question to use e in place of x, and presumably you intend `e` here to be the base of natural logarithms. In that case, your only rational solution (with n rational) is probably a=0, b=0, c=n

Comment: I have completely changed the question. Does the new question make sense?

Comment: Regarding the new question: does the solution `a=0, b=n/e` make sense for you?

Comment: b=n/e isn't a whole number always

Comment: Then, do you need only integer coefficients? This is unclear from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Premise: the following solution finds integer (approximate) coefficients.

An easy way to make your code more efficient is to use [vectorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47755442/what-is-vectorization) (using the `numpy` library) to compute the polynomial on all combination of indices, then return the combination of indices whose value of the polynomial is closer to the value of `n`.

The following code creates a grid of all integer `a` and `b` combinations using [`np.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html), then computes the polynomial on all combinations and computes the positions of the combination making the polynomial closer to `n` using [`np.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html). Lastly, it returns the `a` and `b` values of the combination.

```
import numpy as np

def find_approximate_integer_coefficients(n, x, amin=-10, amax=10, bmin=-10, bmax=10):
    a_range = np.arange(amin, amax+1)
    b_range = np.arange(bmin, bmax+1)

    a_coefficients, b_coefficients = np.meshgrid(a_range, b_range)
    polynomial_value = (a_coefficients * (x ** 2) + b_coefficients * x)

    argmin = np.abs(polynomial_value - n).argmin()
    return a_coefficients.flatten()[argmin], b_coefficients.flatten()[argmin]
```

For instance, `find_approximate_integer_coefficients(7.3890, np.e)` returns `(1, 0)` in about 75 microseconds on my laptop.

You can easily extend the code above to the case of higher-order polynomials as the `np.meshgrid` method accepts an arbitrary number of ranges to create the grid.