# Solve waterhammer PDE in numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pde

I’ve been trying to solve the water hammer PDE’s from the Maple example linked below in python (numpy/scipy). I’m getting very unstable results. Can anyone see my mistake? Guessing something is wrong with the boundary conditions.

https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/view.aspx?path=applications/WaterHammer

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Parameters
Dia = 0.1
V = 14.19058741 # Stead state
p = 1000 # Liquid density
u = 0.001 # Viscosity
L = 25 
e = 0.0001 # Roughness
Psource = 0.510E6
thick = 0.001
E= 7010*10**9
K=20010E6
Vsteady= 14.19058741
Ks = 1/((1/K)+(Dia/E*thick))

# Darcy-Weisbach
def Friction(V):
    Rey = ((Dia*V*p)/u)
    fL = 64/Rey
    fT = 1/((1.8*np.log10((6.9/Rey) + (e/(3.7*Dia))**1.11))**2)
    
    if Rey >= 0 and Rey < 2000:
        return fL
    
    if Rey >= 2000 and Rey<4000:
        return fL + ((fT-fL)*(Rey-2000))/(4000-2000)
     
    if Rey >= 4000:
        return fT
    
    return 0

def model(D, t):
    V = D[:N]
    P = D[N:]
    
    dVdt = np.zeros(N)
    for i in range(1, len(dVdt)-1):
        dVdt[i] = -(1/p)*((P[i+1]-P[i-1])/2*dx)-((Friction(np.abs(V[i]))*(np.abs(V[i])**2))/(2*Dia))
    
    dPdt = np.zeros(N)
    for i in range(1, len(dPdt)-1):
        dPdt[i] = -((V[i+1]-V[i-1])/(2*dx))*Ks
        
    if t < 2:
        dVdt[29] = 0
    else:
        dVdt[29] = -1
     
    dPdt[29] = 0
    dVdt[0] = dVdt[1]
           
    return np.append(dVdt,dPdt)


N = 30
x = np.linspace(0, L, N)
dx = x[1] - x[0]

## Initial conditions
Vi_0 = np.ones(N)*Vsteady
Pi_0 = np.arange(N)
for i in Pi_0:
    Pi_0[i] = Psource - (i*dx/L)*Psource

# initial condition
y0 = np.append(Vi_0, Pi_0)

# time points
t = np.linspace(0,3,10000)

# solve ODE
y = odeint(model,y0,t)

Vr = y[:,0:N]
Pr = y[:,N:]

plt.plot(t,Pr[:,5])
```

[image: Pressure plot]

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but this might prove useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47755442/what-is-vectorization . For instance, the ```for i in Pi_0: Pi_0[i] = Psource - (i*dx/L)*Psource``` may be written as ```Pi_0 = Psource - (Pi_0*dx/L)*Psource```.

Comment: Good point, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just come across this posting and have modified your code to obtain exactly the same results in `python` as from the `Maple` code you cite. The following points are worth making:

- The main problem was your implementation of the `boundary conditions`. The `Maple` version uses `ghost cells` and I have followed
  the same approach.
- I used the `scripy.integrate.solve` integrator as it gives more
  control over the numerical integration. I found that the most
  efficient method (fastest) for this problem was `DOP853`.
- There were also some minor typos.
- I included a calculation of the maximum theoretical pressure as a
  check.
- The problem formulation of the Maple code needs checking as it
  predicts -ve pressures.

The python code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
from scipy import integrate
# from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

t_start = time.time()

## Parameters
p = 1000                       # Liquid density
K = 200*1E6                    # Bulk Modulus of Liquid
u = 0.001                      # Viscosity
Dia = 0.1                      # Pipe Diameter
thick = 0.001                  # Pipe Thickness
e = 0.0001                     # Roughness
L = 25                         # Length of Pipe
E = 70*1E9                     # Young's Modulus
A = (np.pi*Dia**2)/4           # Cross-sectional Area
Psource = 0.5*1E6              # Pressure at Start of Pipeline
Ks = 1/((1/K)+(Dia/(E*thick))) # Effective Modulus of system

Vsteady = 14.19058741          # Steady State (from Maple)
a0 = np.sqrt(K/p)              # Speed of Sound

# Darcy-Weisbach
def Friction(V):
    Rey = ((Dia*V*p)/u)
    fL = 64/Rey
    fT = 1/((1.8*np.log10((6.9/Rey) + (e/(3.7*Dia))**1.11))**2)
    
    if Rey > 0 and Rey < 2000:
        return fL    
    elif Rey >= 2000 and Rey<4000:
        return fL + ((fT-fL)*(Rey-2000))/(4000-2000)
    elif Rey >= 4000:
        return fT    
    else: 
      return 0

def model(t, D):
    V = np.zeros(N+2)    # Allocate Nodes with ghost cells   
    P = np.zeros(N+2)
    
    V[1:N+1] = D[0:N]    # Populate Node Data
    P[1:N+1] = D[N:2*N]
    
    dVdt = np.zeros(N+2) # Allocate Derivative vars with ghost cells
    dPdt = np.zeros(N+2)
    if t >= t_trip:
      # Set ghost cells equal to BCs, as Maple
      V[0] = V[1]
      P[0] = Psource
      V[N+1] = Vsteady*np.exp(-70*(t-t_trip))
      P[N+1] = 0
      
      for i in range(1, N+1):
          dVdt[i] = -(1/p)*(P[i+1]-P[i-1])/(2*dx)- \
                     ((Friction(np.abs(V[i]))*(V[i]*np.abs(V[i])))/(2*Dia))   
      for i in range(1, N+1):
          dPdt[i] = -((V[i+1]-V[i-1])/(2*dx))*Ks

    return np.append(dVdt[1:N+1],dPdt[1:N+1])

N = 30
x = np.linspace(0, L, N)
dx = x[1] - x[0]

## Initial conditions
Vi_0 = np.ones(N)*Vsteady
Pi_0 = np.zeros(N)
for i in range(N):
    Pi_0[i] = Psource - (i*dx/L)*Psource
y0 = np.append(Vi_0, Pi_0)

# time points
t0 = 0.0
tf = 3.0
t_trip = 2

# solve ODE
method = "DOP853" #"LSODA","DOP853","BDF","RK23","RK45,Radau""
tol = 1.e-12
out = sc.integrate.solve_ivp(fun=model,
      t_span=[t0,tf], y0=y0,
      method=method, first_step=1e-6, max_step=0.0001,
      rtol=tol, atol=tol)

print(r"Integration Success =", out.success)
print(out.message)

dP_max = p*a0*Vsteady
print(f"Maximum Theoretical Pressure = {dP_max/10**6:.2f} [MPa]")

t_end = time.time()
total_time = t_end-t_start
print(f"Elapsed Time = {total_time:.2f}")

t = out.t
sol = out.y

Vr = sol[0:N,:]
Pr = sol[N:2*N,:]

plotNode = N-1
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
ax1, ax2 = fig.subplots(2)
fig.suptitle(f'Water Hammer Plots at Node: {plotNode}',
             fontsize=20)
ax1.plot(t,Pr[plotNode,:])
ax2.plot(t,Vr[plotNode,:])

ax1.set_xlabel('time [s]', fontsize=16)
ax1.set_ylabel('Pr [Pa]', fontsize=16)
ax2.set_xlabel('time [s]', fontsize=16) 
ax2.set_ylabel('Vr [m/s]',fontsize=16)
ax1.grid()
ax2.grid()
fig.tight_layout()
```

The output plots generated by the `python` code are included.
[image]